# Android -RecyclerView in kitkat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

since the RecyclerView src is in android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView can i use the recyclerView in kit kat and jelly bean as long as i reference this package from the support library (or google play services)?

Comment: why do you think you cannot use it in kitkat?

Comment: i thought it was for L and beyond.

Comment: if something is in the support library that means it can be used in anything above the specific version of that support library

Comment: no its not api 21 its `revision 21`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If something is in the support library that means it can be used in any API down to what version of the support library it is.

for example v7 support library means you can use that library on any app that supports API 7 and up.

it is not API exclusive, all the 21 means is what `revision` it is